# How to list all public RSA .pem file on any machine

Tags: certificate, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rsa

Sorry for changing completely my question but I cannot delete it. I hope that reformulating my question will shape a better question.

I'm trying to find all public RSA `.pem` files on Windows/Linux.

```
sudo find / |grep "\.pem"
```

Seems a valid solution to me (since we have WSL on Windows) but it would be even better if I could also print the length of the key.

Unfortunately when I try:

```
sudo find / |grep "\.pem" | openssl x509 -text -noout | grep "Public-Key"
```

It doesn't print the key length and is simply saying that cannot access a few directories (Linux bash on Windows). 
But I'm root!

Comment: That directory is for persisted keys (almost all are private keys) from the older of the two Windows Cryptography systems.  Certificate stores are another system, and are (IIRC) largely registry-based.

Comment: @bartonjs, so where can I find a list of Public Key in Windows?

Comment: Public _keys_? I have no idea.  Certificates? The certificate store APIs or PowerShell interactions. Converting the API/PS representation to the PEM format is a step you have to do yourself, they won't be in the PEM format anywhere in the system.

Answer (score 0):

This PowerShell command will list all the certificates of the current user:

```
Get-Childitem Cert:\currentUser -Recurse
```

You may find more information in the description of the
[Get-Childitem command](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-childitem?view=powershell-6).

Comment: thank you but this command will just LIST them, how can I open and READ one certificate?

Comment: What do you mean by read? Export them, then use some utility? The Windows Certificates applet can do this.

Comment: I need the directory so I can work on them